# Codeignighter Record wont insert

Tags: mysql, insert

Using CI for the first time and i'm smashing my head with this seemingly simple issue. My query wont insert the record.

In an attempt to debug a possible problem, the insert code has been simplified but i'm still getting no joy.

Essentially, i'm using;

```
$data = array('post_post' => $this->input->post('ask_question'));
$this->db->insert('posts', $data);
```

I'm getting no errors (although that possibly due to disabling them in config/database.php due to another CI related trauma :-$ )

Ive used

```
echo print $this->db->last_query();
```

to get the generated query, shown as below:

```
INSERT INTO `posts` (`post_post`) VALUES ('some text')
```

I have pasted this query into phpMyAdmin, it inserts no problem. Ive even tried using `$this->db->query()` to run the outputted query above 'manually' but again, the record will not insert.

The scheme of the DB table 'posts' is simply two columns, post_id & post_post.

Please, any pointers on whats going on here would be greatly appreciated...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK..Solved, after much a messing with CI.

Got it to work by setting persistant connection to false.

`$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;`

*sigh*

Answer (score 0):

Things generally look ok, everything you have said suggests that it should work. My first instinct would be to check that what you're inserting is compatible with your SQL field.

Just a cool CI feature; I'd suggest you take a look at the [CI Database Transaction](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html) class. Transactions allow you to wrap your query/queries inside a transaction, which can be rolled back on failure, and can also make error handling easier:

```
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO posts ...etc ');
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
    {
        // generate an error... or use the log_message() function to log your error
    }
```

Alternatively, one thing you can do is put your Insert SQL statement into $this->db->[query](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html)(your_query_here), instead of calling insert. There is a CI Query feature called [Query](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html) Binding which will also auto-escape your passed data array.

Let me know how it goes, and hope this helps!

Comment: No, wont work. Ive checked the fields to make sure the string of text can be inserted. Ive checked the users DB permissions to check they can add, ive tried another table, using your code above the if statement isnt triggered. What am I missing??? :<